# can we automate migration through open nebula?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have started my research project with this line.open nebula and kvm as base.even I want to detect hotspots and handle automatic migration.but got stuck up without knowing where to customize the code.can u help me

Comment: Show what you've done so far. Make the question more precise.

Comment: I have created opennebula front end and trying to add the host to it.

Comment: I have created opennebula front end and trying to add the host to it.But I am getting    " Unable to monitor the host" error.